# Set a view on screen-properities

Tags: java, android, button, random, view

In the code below, the button change it's position on click. but sometimes, the button moves out of the screen, result it can't be clicked anymore. how to fix that?

```
@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

view.getParent();
    Random r = new Random();
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int screenWidth = decorView.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = decorView.getHeight();
      long startTime =  SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
      i++;


    if (i == 1 ) {

        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }
    if (i == 2 ) {
        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }

    else if (i == 3) {
        long difference = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()  - startTime;

          Intent intent = new Intent(Game.this, MainScreen.class);
          intent.putExtra("time",difference);

          textview1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("time"));
        finish();
    }


}
```

Comment: what is the layout of the activity, maybe the parent of the button not the whole screen, you used decorView to get width and hight of the parent! you should take this values from the parent view of the button.

Comment: Layout is relative layout. how to get the value from the parents?

Comment: use view.getParent() to get the parent view then get the layout params you need from the parent view

Comment: updated code : view cannot be resolved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem you are having is you might be using `wrap_content` as width/height in your `RelativeLayout`, but you grab the screen's width&height rather than the layout which contains your button.

you should use the `getParent()` method to get your `RelativeLayout` width&height.

```
RelativeLayout myRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) myButton.getParent();
int screenWidth = myRelativeLayout.getWidth();
int screenHeight = myRelativeLayout.getHeight();
```